# How to fix rounding error

Tags: c#, math

I am getting this out put from the code which will follow:

49

49.000000000000000000000000001

I want to know how to fix it so I get back to 49.

```
decimal a = 49;
decimal b = 24;

decimal result = a / b;

decimal c = result * b;

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

the windows 10 calculator app get it right and its using more precision I guess.
There has to be a way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: why can't you just use `int`?

Comment: Are you sure that windows app doesn't just round it? Good question non the less.

Comment: Relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually want a *lower* precision type to do the math. If you use a double type, it works fine:

```
double a = 49;
double b = 24;

double result = a / b;
double c = result * b;

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using one number to store a quotient, use two numbers to store a quotient.

```
decimal a = 49;
decimal b = 24;

decimal resultNumerator = a;
decimal resultDenominator = b;

decimal c = (resultNumerator * b) / resultDenominator;

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Comment: What! No. Sorry.

Comment: Also, what is the point of `resultNumerator` and `resultDenominator`? This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: If you postpone all division operations until it's time to display a result, the precision problem disappears.